# Porque me dice que no esta definida la variable? PHP

Tags: php, xampp

cuando le paso por postman el parametro que espera me dice:

```
 Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Service\LoginGeneral.php on line 25
 {"resultado":"NONE","mensaje":"Numero no encontrado"}
```

Este es mi codigo php:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
 if($_GET['url'] == "user")
        {
             
                $identificador = $_POST['id'];
                
                
                $respuesa = Registro::ObtenerDatosID($identificador);
    
                $contenedor = array();
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    if($respuesa){
                        $contenedor["resultado"]="OK";
                        $contenedor["datos"]= $respuesa;
                        echo json_encode($contenedor);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo json_encode(array("resultado" => 'NONE',"mensaje" =>'Numero no encontrado'));
                    }
        }
}
```

Dentro de la clase Registro tengo una funcion.

```html
public static function ObtenerDatosID($id){
                /* */
                $consultar = "SELECT NOMBRE_EMP FROM USUARIOS where NUMERO_EMP= ?";
                try{
                $resultado= Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);

                    $resultado->execute(array($id));

                    $tabla = $resultado ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    return $tabla;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Lo m{as simple es que no estes mandando la ID... antes de todo, has un echo $_POST["id"] a ver que muestra

Comment: @Excorpion ya hice el echo y si llega el dato que le estoy mandando

Comment: Entonces, muestra cual es la linea 25, y detalle mejor el error

Comment: ya corregi lo de la linea del error ahora entra directamente el else y me trae  {"resultado":"NONE","mensaje":"Numero no encontrado"} no ejecuta el query por cierto estoy usando sql server

Comment: ya pero.. cual es la linea del error ?? cual es la linea 25 ??